# Android multiple MediaPlayer instances in sync?

Tags: android, audio, media-player, soundpool, mixing

I need to be able to have multiple tracks playing at the same time, and also changing to other tracks with as little latency as possible. I don't think SoundPool will work, since it are real audiotracks and not so much samples. I'm trying to make like some sort of mixing application, where you can select certain tracks to play, and others not to play.
Any idea on how to do this, suggestions/tips ?

Comment: Did you consider to use android.media.AudioTrack? You'd push in PCM data and make mixing yourself from other PCM sources.

Comment: Never knew that existed, looks complicated tough! Any good sources on how to use it (setting up multiple channels etc...) ?